# What happened to Androidx.annotation.keep, and what's the new solution?

Tags: java, android, androidx

I tried to upgrade my android annotations to:

```
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0"
```

...but now these three imports fail:

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
```

What's the new way to implement these?  I need @Keep to make sure the java classes exist for my native code to call them.

(Note: The official Google documents pretend nothing has changed and everything's fine)

(Note2: Falling back to annotation:1.5.0 works, but what's the new solution?)

Answer (score 0):

Was there any follow up on this?

I'm having a similar issue with some modifications to the AOSP framework, but only with the @Keep annotation.

For your issue, have you tried using proguard rules? You can learn more about them here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html.

Something like this should work as a replacement for the @Keep annotation.:

```
-keep public class com.example.** { public protected *; }
```

AFAIK The @NonNull annotation still exists, I haven't had any compilation or runtime issues with it.

My current issue is that the CTS testing for AOSP requires that no `androidx` references exist in the BOOTCLASSPATH or SHAREDLIBS, and this is the last reference I need to get rid of.